# Вызов внешней программы и считывание данных, которые та выводит в свой стандартный поток вывода

Tags: c++, windows, windows-8

Как написать функцию на С++, которая будет  запускать другую программу и считывать данные, которые та выводит в свой стандартный поток вывода.

Comment: [man popen](http://www.opennet.ru/cgi-bin/opennet/man.cgi?topic=popen)

Comment: Пожалуйста, укажите операционную систему, т.к. в самом C++ нет средств, чтобы добиться того, чего Вы хотите — придётся использовать средства ОС.

Comment: @ixSci Операционная система Windows 8.

Comment: Ответ [тот же](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/96ayss4b.aspx) :-)

Comment: @Pink Tux спасибо, разобрался! Вот ссылка: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/96ayss4b.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Аналог popen под Windows [_popen](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/popen-wpopen?view=vs-2019):

```
pipe = _popen("<command with arguments>", "rt" );
```